# help evaluating tricky contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am a 16 year old in Sweden learning complex analysis and I'm trying to evaluate the integral (I've checked that it converges)
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\ dx $$
($e^{ix}$ to give the answer to both the integrals with $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$)

Taking $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^3+z^2+z+1} = \frac{e^{iz}}{(z+1)(z+i)(z-i)}$ with poles at $z=-i,\ z=i,\ z=-1\ $ as the integrand I constructed a counter-clockwise oriented contour C not enclosing any singularity as a quarter circle with radius R centered on the origin, C being made up of the a circular arc $\Gamma $, the real number line from $0$ to R named $\Lambda$, the semicircular arc with radius $\epsilon$ around the right side of the singularity at $z=i$ named $\gamma $, and the imaginary number line from $0$ to $i$R, broken up by $\gamma $ called $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, $\psi_1$ being the one from $i-i\epsilon$ to $0$ and $\psi_2$ being from $i$R to $i+i\epsilon$.

Summarized: $$\oint_{C}^{}f(z)\ dz = \int_{\Gamma }^{}f(z)\ dz + \int_{\gamma }^{}f(z)\ dz + \int_{\Lambda }^{}f(z)\ dz + \int_{\psi_1}^{}f(z)\ dz + \int_{\psi_2}^{}f(z)\ dz$$

By Cauchy's residue theorem the integral over C equals $0$ as it doesn't enclose any poles.

Using Jordan's Lemma i found the intgral over $\Gamma$ to be $0$ as R approaches infnity, likewise
the integral over $\Lambda$ yields the answer $I$ I'm looking for as R approaches infinity.
Since $\gamma$ is a right-facing semicircle with radius $\epsilon$ centered at the point $z=i$ I parametarized it in the following way: $$z=\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}+i,\ t \in [0, \pi]$$
$$dz=-i\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}\ dt$$
The integrand after factorizing the denominator and is therefore
$$\frac{e^{i(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}+i)}}{(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i+i)(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i-i)(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i+1)}(-i\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)})\ dt$$
silplifying:
$$(-i)\frac{e^{i(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i)}}{(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+2i)(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i+1)}\ dt$$ making the integral over $\gamma$ equal to $$-i\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{e^{i(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i)}}{(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+2i)(\epsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi }{2}-t)}+i+1)} \ dt$$
in the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$, the integral approaches $$-i\int_{0}^{\pi } \frac{e^{-1}}{1+3i}\ dt = \frac{-\pi}{e}\left (\frac{3+i}{10}  \right )$$

However I am unsure how to evaluate the integrals over $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, if you can combine them into one integral when $\epsilon$ approaches zero since it would integrate over all numbers from $i$R to $0$ except for $z=i$ or if there's some obscure theorem or something I don't know about, otherwise I don't know if there's anything I can do except integrate it non-elementary which defeats the entire purpouse of contour integrating in the first place.

Comment: Usually what one does to avoid computation is to relate the value of one ray to a constant multiple of another ray ($\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz = k \int_{\gamma_2}f(e^{i\theta}z)e^{i\theta}dz$) but given the locations of the poles there is no rotational symmetry about the positive real axis you could use.

Comment: Performing summation ,
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x^3+x^2+x+1}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}(1-x)}{1-x^4}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{(1+x^2)(1+x)}\ dx$$
Choosing a quarter-circle contour in the upper-half of the complex plane and leaving the pole at $x=i$ outside the contour, I got
$$I=\frac{i}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-z}}{1+iz}dz+\frac{i}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-z}(1-iz)}{1+z}dz-\frac{i}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-z}(1-iz)}{z-1}dz-\frac{\pi e^{-1}(1-i)}{4}$$
The real and imaginary parts can be expressed via special functions (exponential integral $E_i(z)$)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Beautiful idea!! I did not see that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the kind of answer you're looking for, but there is a way to "avoid" integrating over $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ by evaluating the Cauchy Principal Value (P.V.). I decided to add it as an answer because there's not enough space in the comments, so feel free to say this post doesn't help or downvote it.

**(Answer)** Let's use the same $f(z)$ you defined. By Cauchy's Residue Theorem and by following the counterclockwise direction you defined in your post, you can rewrite $\oint_C f(z)dz$ as

$$0 = \int_{\Lambda}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \text{P.V.}\int_{iR}^0 f(z)dz - i\pi\text{Res}(f(z), z=i),$$

which we can reorganize as

$$\int_{\Lambda}f(z)dz = 0  + \text{P.V.}\int_{0}^{iR} f(z)dz + i\pi\text{Res}(f(z), z=i).$$

(Notice by the Squeeze Theorem that the integral over $\Gamma$ converges to $0$ as $R\to\infty$. I can fill out the proof for that if you  need me to.)

Calculating that residue, we get

$$i\pi\text{Res}(f(z), z=i) = i\pi\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+1)(z+i)(z-i)} = \frac{\pi}{4e}(1-i).$$

Next comes the tricky part, which is the Principal Value integral. (Notice without the P.V., that integral diverges). Letting $z=iu$, we can rewrite that integral as

$$\text{P.V.}\int_{0}^{iR} f(z)dz = \text{P.V.}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{ie^{-u}}{-iu^{3}-u^{2}+iu+1}du = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{ie^{-u}}{-iu^{3}-u^{2}+iu+1}du + \int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{ie^{-u}}{-iu^{3}-u^{2}+iu+1}du\right).$$

The reason why I say this post might not be helpful and why I put "avoid" in quotation marks is that I have no idea how to calculate those last two integrals. If someone could help me in the comments with that, that'd be great and I would credit you for it if I edit my post.

But I decided to rely on WolframAlpha and this is what I got:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%281%2F4+-+i%2F4%29+%CF%80%29%2Fe+%2B+i%28integral+e%5E%28-x%29+%2F+%28-ix%5E3-x%5E2%2Bix%2B1%29+from+0+to+0.9999999%29+%2B+i%28integral+e%5E%28-x%29+%2F+%28-ix%5E3-x%5E2%2Bix%2B1%29+from+1.0000001+to+infinity%29

WolframAlpha also approximates the original integral as

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+e%5E%28ix%29+%2F+%28x%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29+from+0+to+infinity

So just by numerical approximations, my process seems correct.

**(Thoughts)** If you wanted to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1}dx$ (or $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1}dx$), the process would be the same except you'd be taking the imaginary (or real) part of each integral. I didn't try it out because I don't know if you want to try that.