# Cauchy principal value: methods

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

I don't understand yet the logic in the Cauchy Principale Value (P.V.) calculations. Let the resideu theorem:

$$\color{red}{\oint_Cf(z) \ dz = 2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^n \underset{z=z_k}{Res}\{f(z)\}}$$

(we supposed that $C$ was a "nice" closed curb and $f(z)$ analytical $\forall z \in \mathrm{int} \ C$ except in $z_k$ ($1 \le k \le n$))

I've got 2 poorly justified examples in my exercice book (forgive me for non-mathjaxing all of that follows) :

[image: 1st example]

Apparently, the corrector found a nice closed curb, but don't want to share how he did it. Usually, when $f(z)$ is pair, we can define such a $C$ curb:
[image: the cup]

but it doesn't explain **why the 2 factor is missing in the answer**. Why $\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$ ?

---

Second example:
$$P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\exp(-4ix)}{(x+i)^2} \ dx$$

Here, we have a reversed cup (why reversed ?) $\gamma (R)$ with the segment $C(R)$:

[image: 2cd example]

Again, I don't understand what has been done. Is there a general methode I can understand to solve those 2 exercices ?

---

**EDIT**: corrected one error pointed out in the comments ($(x+i)^2$ instead of $(x+1)^2$)

Comment: Did you type your second example correctly, or did you confuse $1$ and $i$? The picture is correct but the integral above doesn't seem to be correct, after estimating the principal value of it.

Comment: Anyways, I'll type up an alternate answer later as to why there is a $\pi i$ instead of a $2\pi i$.

Comment: The equations you see (except the 1st one) are screenshots of my book. Normally, they are correct, but it is not 100% guarenteed

Comment: I meant for the second example are you evaluating $P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(4ix)}{(x+1)^2}$dx or $P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(4ix)}{(x+i)^2}$dx? Your screenshot of the book has the second one but you typed the first one.

Comment: I'm currently typing my solution right now. Your second example is hard to understand. By cup, do you mean the entire contour? And do you mean "reversed cup" as in traversing in the opposite direction or the entire cup flipped upside down?

Comment: You are right, seems like I made an error, I will correct it

Comment: Yes, I meant the reversed cup, just like the red contour in my picture but reversed (the other half of the circle + the segment $x \in [-R, R]$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to answer all your questions, let's start at the beginning.

---

For the first example, let $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z+1)(z^2+2)}$ and define a counterclockwise contour as

$$C := [-R, -1-\epsilon] \cup \gamma \cup [-1+\epsilon, R] \cup \Gamma,$$

where $\gamma$ is the semicircular indent enclosing the pole at $z_0 := -1$ with a small radius $\epsilon$, and $\Gamma$ is the bigger semicircle of a large radius $R$. (There is a visual provided by the other answerer.) By Cauchy's Residue Theorem,

$$
\eqalign{
2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=\sqrt{2}i) &= \int_{-R}^{-1-\epsilon}f(z)dz + \int_{-1+\epsilon}^{R}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \cr
&= \operatorname{P.V.}\int_{-R}^{R}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \cr
2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=\sqrt{2}i) + \int_{-\gamma}f(z)dz &= \operatorname{P.V.}\int_{-R}^{R}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz,
}
$$

where we used one of the definitions of the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

---

**(Answer)** Given the above conditions, we will prove

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\gamma}f(z)dz = i\pi\operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=-1).$$

*Proof.* Enclosing the pole $z_0 := -1$, the function can be expressed as

$$f(z) = g(z) + \displaystyle \sum_{n=-k}^{0} b_{2n-1}(z-z_0)^{2n-1}$$

such that $g(z)$ is analytic at $z_0 = -1$. Thus,

$$\int_{-\gamma}f(z)dz = \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz + \displaystyle\int_{-\gamma}\sum_{n=-k}^{0}b_{2n-1}(z+1)^{2n-1}dz.$$

Taking $\epsilon \to 0$ on both sides, we will show that $\int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz \to 0$ by using the Estimation Lemma:

$$
\displaystyle
\eqalign{
0 &\leq \left|i\epsilon \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz\right| \leq \epsilon \pi \sup(g(z), z \in -\gamma) \cr
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 0 &\leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left|i\epsilon \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz\right| \leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \pi \sup(g(z), z \in -\gamma) \cr
0 &\leq  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left|i\epsilon \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz\right| \leq 0. \cr
}
$$

As $\epsilon \to 0$, the Squeeze Theorem yields $\displaystyle \left|i\epsilon \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz\right| \to 0$, implying that $\displaystyle i\epsilon \int_{-\gamma}g(z)dz \to 0$ as well.

For the other contour integral, let $z = \epsilon e^{i\theta}-1$for $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. This parameterization results in

$$
\displaystyle
\eqalign{
ia\int_{0}^{\pi}\sum_{n=-k}^{0}b_{2n-1}\left(ae^{i\theta}\right)^{2n-1}e^{i\theta}d\theta &= i\int_{0}^{\pi}\sum_{n=-k}^{0}b_{2n-1}\left(ae^{i\theta}\right)^{2n}d\theta \cr
&= i\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=-k}^{-1}b_{2n-1}\left(ae^{i\theta}\right)^{2n}+b_{-1}\right)d\theta \cr
&= i\sum_{n=-k}^{-1}b_{2n-1}a^{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2ni\theta}d\theta+ib_{-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \cr
&= 0+i\pi b_{-1} \cr
&= i\pi \operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=-1), \cr
}
$$

where we used the fact that $e^{2ni\theta}$ has a period $\pi$ to make the integral vanish.

Therefore, we are done. *Q.E.D.*

---

As for the second example, it is hard to understand, but I believe this is what the book did. Consider the usual semi-circular contour of radius $R$ but in the third and fourth quadrants, traversed clockwise. Let $C(R)$ be the segment and $\gamma(R)$ be the semicircle such that its ends connect the ends of $C(R)$. Let $f(z) = \dfrac{\exp(-4ix)}{(x+i)^2}$. Then by Cauchy's Residue Theorem, we get

$$\displaystyle \lim_{R \to \infty} -2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=-i) = \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{C(R)}f(z)dz - \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{-\gamma(R)}f(z)dz,$$

and the desired result follows, after some work.

---

> but it doesn't explain **why the 2 factor is missing in the answer**. Why $\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$ ?

As you probably have observed, the semicircular indent at the pole $z_0 = -1$ does not necessarily involve the famous [Residue Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html) because, as you have acknowledged, the path is not closed. The first proof in this answer explains why. The calculations should be straightforward from here.

> I don't understand yet the logic in the Cauchy Principale Value (P.V.) calculations.

It is just a matter of understanding the definition of the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). When you take the Cauchy Principal Value of an improper integral, you split up the integral at the "difficult" point/singularity/pole and take an $\epsilon \to 0^+$ near the difficult point.

> Again, I don't understand what has been done. Is there a general methode I can understand to solve those 2 exercices ?

It is just a matter of practice. If they help, you can refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537225/why-does-using-the-laurent-series-for-frac-cos-2zz2-give-a-different-res/4537272#4537272) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524767/help-evaluating-tricky-contour-integral/4524888#4524888).

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll read your answer carefully a bit later when I will have more time for it

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
[image]

Contour: Semi-circle in the upper complex half plane with an indent around $\ds{x = -1}$.

Integration along the upper arc *vanishes out* as $\ds{R \to \infty}$.
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\ \left\{%
\int_{-\infty}^{-1 - \epsilon}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 2}} +
\int_{\pi}^{0}{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta \over
\pars{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}\bracks{\pars{-1 + \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}^{2} + 2}}\right.}
\\ & \color{#44f}{\left.\phantom{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\,\,}\int_{-1 + \epsilon}^{\infty}\,\,
{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 2}}\right\}} =
2\pi\ic\on{Res}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 2}}, x = \root{2}\ic}
\\[5mm] & \implies
\mbox{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 2}} - {\pi\ic \over 3} = 2\pi\ic\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2\root{2}\pars{\root{2} - \ic}}}
\\ - & -----------------------------------
\\[5mm] & \implies
\mbox{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 2}}  = 2\pi\ic\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2\root{2}\pars{\root{2} - \ic}}} + {\pi \ic \over 3}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{{\root{2} \over 6}\,\pi}} \approx 0.7405
\\ &
\end{align}

Comment: I understand the calculus, thanks. However, I don't understand how you apply the residue theroem to a non-closed path

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg I just put a contour picture.