# How to prove: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+e^{\tfrac{\pi x}{m}}}dx= \dfrac{1}{4}(2+m\tanh(\tfrac{m}{2})-m\coth(\tfrac{m}{2}))$, $m=1,2,3,...$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to prove: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+e^{\tfrac{\pi x}{m}}}dx= \dfrac{1}{4}\left(2+m\tanh(\tfrac{m}{2})-m\coth(\tfrac{m}{2})\right)$, $m=1,2,3,...$

I m trying to solve an exercise and I end up in the above integral, when I put this in  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%28sinx%29%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%28pi%20x%29%2F%2899%29%29%29%20from%20x%3D0%20to%20infty) I get the result on the right. But I am stuck and cannot solve the integral.

Comment: My initial guess is contour integration using complex analysis

Comment: After my last formula, use the half angle identities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{ix}}{1+e^{\tfrac{\pi x}{m}}}dx\\
&=&\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-(\tfrac{\pi}{m}-i)x}}{1+e^{-\tfrac{\pi x}{m}}}dx\\
&=&\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-((n+1)\tfrac{\pi }{m}-i)x}dx\\
&=&\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-((n+1)\tfrac{\pi }{m}-i)x}dx\\
&=&\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{m}{(n+1)\pi-mi}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\tfrac{m^2}{(n+1)^2\pi^2+m^2}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\tfrac{m^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2+m^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tfrac{m^2}{4n^2\pi^2+m^2}\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4}\left(2+m\tanh(\tfrac{m}{2})-m\coth(\tfrac{m}{2})\right).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

Considring first
$$I=\int \frac{e^{i x}}{1+e^{k x}}\,dx$$
$$x=\frac{\log (t)}{k} \implies I=\frac 1k \int \frac{t^{-1+\frac{i}{k}}}{1+t}\,dt$$ Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=-i\, t^{i/k}\, \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{i}{k};1+\frac{i}{k};-t\right)$$
$$J=\int \frac{\sin(x)}{1+e^{k x}}\,dx$$
$$J=-\frac{e^{-ix}}{2} \,
   _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{i}{k};\frac{k-i}{k};-e^{kx}\right)-\frac{e^{ix}}{2}  \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{i}{k};\frac{k+i}{k};-e^{kx}\right)$$
$$K=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{1+e^{k x}}\,dx=\frac 12-\frac \pi{2k}\text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

For any real $m > 0$, we will prove, using a rectangular-like contour, that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{1+e^{\frac{\pi x}{m}}}dx = \frac{1}{4}\left(2+m\tanh\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)-m\coth\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\right).$$

**Proof.** Let $\displaystyle f\left(z\right)=\frac{e^{iz}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi z}{m}}}$. Its set of singularities is $\left\{k \in \mathbb{Z} : (2k+1)mi \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$, but the pole we will choose from that set is $z=mi$. Suppose $m > \epsilon > 0$. Define a rectangular-like contour $C = [0, R] \cup [R, 2mi + R] \cup [2mi + R, 2mi] \cup [2mi, i(m + \epsilon)] \cup \delta \cup [i(m - \epsilon), 0]$ where $\delta$ is a semicircular curve of small radius $\epsilon$ indented on the path from $2mi$ to $0$. It encloses the pole we chose earlier. Applying Cauchy's Residue Theorem and the Cauchy Principal Value yields

$$
\eqalign{
0 &= \left(\int_{0}^{R}+\int_{R}^{2mi+R}+\int_{2mi+R}^{2mi}+\int_{\delta}^{ }+P.V.\int_{2mi}^{0}\right)f\left(z\right)dz \cr
\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{0}^{R}f\left(z\right)dz &= \lim_{R \to \infty}\left(-\int_{R}^{2mi+R}f\left(z\right)dz+\int_{2mi}^{2mi+R}f\left(z\right)dz\right)+\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\operatorname{P.V.}\int_{0}^{2mi}f\left(z\right)dz-\int_{\delta}^{ }f\left(z\right)dz\right). \cr
}
$$
It can be proved that the second integral approaches $0$ as $R \to \infty$ by mapping $z \to R + iz$, using the theorem $\displaystyle \left|\int_{a}^{b}f\left(z\right)dz\right|\ \le\int_{a}^{b}\left|f\left(z\right)\right|dz$, and using the Squeeze Theorem.

Rewriting the third integral gives

$$
\eqalign{
\int_{2mi}^{2mi+R}f\left(z\right)dz &= \int_{0}^{R}f\left(u+2mi\right)d\left(u+2mi\right) \cr
&= \int_{0}^{R}\frac{e^{i\left(u+2mi\right)}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi}{m}\left(u+2mi\right)}}d\left(u+2mi\right) \cr
&= e^{-2m}\int_{0}^{R}f\left(z\right)dz. \cr
}
$$
Rewriting the fourth integral yields
$$\int_{0}^{2mi}f\left(z\right)dz=\int_{0}^{2m}f\left(iu\right)d\left(iu\right)=\int_{0}^{2m}\frac{e^{i\left(iu\right)}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi}{m}\left(iu\right)}}d\left(iu\right)=i\int_{0}^{2m}\frac{e^{-u}}{1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}u}}du.$$
Using the same idea from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581220/cauchy-principal-value-methods/4585933#4585933), we evaluate the fifth integral as $\epsilon \to 0$ as follows:
$$
\eqalign{
-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\delta}\frac{e^{iz}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi z}{m}}} &= i\pi\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi z}{m}}}, z = mi\right) \cr
&= i\pi\left(\frac{e^{i\left(mi\right)}}{\frac{d}{dz}\Big[1+e^{\frac{\pi}{m}z}\Big]_{z=mi}}\right) \cr
&= \frac{i\pi e^{-m}}{\frac{\pi}{m}e^{\frac{\pi}{m}mi}} \cr
&= -ime^{-m}.
}
$$
Going back to $\displaystyle \oint_{C} f(z)dz$ and doing some rearrangements, we get

$$
\eqalign{
\int_{0}^{R}f\left(z\right)dz &= e^{-2m}\int_{0}^{R}f\left(u\right)du +\operatorname{P.V.}i\int_{0}^{2m}\frac{e^{-u}}{1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}u}}du -ime^{-m} \cr
\implies \Im\int_{0}^{R}f\left(z\right)dz &= \frac{1}{1-e^{-2m}}\Im\left(\operatorname{P.V.}i\int_{0}^{2m}e^{-u}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}u}}\right)du-ime^{-m}\right) \cr
&= \frac{1}{1-e^{-2m}}\left(\operatorname{P.V.}\int_{0}^{2m}e^{-u}\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}u}}\right)du-me^{-m}\right) \cr
&= \frac{1}{1-e^{-2m}}\left(P.V.\int_{0}^{2m}e^{-u}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du-me^{-m}\right) \cr
&= \frac{1}{1-e^{-2m}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2m}-me^{-m}\right) \cr
&= \frac{1}{4}\left(2+m\tanh\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)-m\coth\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\right). \cr
}
$$

Since the value of the integral is independent as $R \to \infty$, we are done!

**Q.E.D.**